# Reference QoQ in CFSpreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfspreadsheet

I've inherited a page that builds an inventory query from four table and outputs them with a QoQ:

```
<cfoutput query="getParts">
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="jobdata">
       select *
       from getJobs
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="orderdata">
       select *
       from getOrders
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="receiptdata">
       select *
       from getIncoming
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>

     <tr>
       <td>#partnum#</td>
       <td align="center">#partdescription#</td>
       <td align="center">#allocated#</td>
       <td align="center">#onhand#</td>
       <td align="center">#receiptdata.recqty#</td>
       <td align="center">#jobdata.JobCount#</td>
       <td align="center">#jobdata.QtyNeeded#</td>
       <td align="center">#jobdata.qtySent#</td>
       <td align="center">#orderdata.ordercount#</td>
       <td align="center">#orderdata.ordered#</td>
       <td align="center">#orderdata.shipqty#</td>
     </tr>
</cfoutput>

<cfset filenametouse = 'myFile' />
<cfset theDir = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) /> 
<cfset theFile = theDir & filenametouse & ".xls" /> 

<cflock name="fileActionSentItems" type="exclusive" timeout="30" throwontimeout="true">
<cfset SpreadsheetObj = spreadsheetNew()>
<cfset fcol = {}>
<cfset fcol.dataformat = "@">

<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(SpreadsheetObj, "Part Number, Description, Allocated, On Hand, Pending Receipt, Job Count, Qty Needed, Qty Issued, Order Count, Qty Ordered, Qty Shipped")>

<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(SpreadsheetObj,"NOT SURE HOW TO GET DATA HERE")>
<cfset SpreadsheetFormatColumn(SpreadsheetObj,fcol,11)>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="SpreadsheetObj" sheetname="Sheet1" overwrite="true" />
```

I am not certain how to reference the data to populate the cells as it comes from multiple queries.  Rewriting the query into one has been a challenge and I'm trying a different route to see if there is another way I don't see.

Comment: Re: *Rewriting the query into one has been a challenge* Just curious but how complex are the database queries and how much data? Because querying within a loop is usually a last resort, even with QoQ's.

Comment: Thanks again, Leigh.  [Theses are the original queries](http://pastebin.com/ZmyPQKTi).  I've been working on combining them all, but haven't gotten far.

Comment: Looks like the first three are all aggregating by the same partnum and description. Try merging them and see if totals work out right. http://pastebin.com/Fxa0Xkj2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
<cfset filenametouse = 'myFile' />
<cfset theDir = GetDirectoryFromPath(GetCurrentTemplatePath()) /> 
<cfset theFile = theDir & filenametouse & ".xls" /> 

<cflock name="fileActionSentItems" type="exclusive" timeout="30" throwontimeout="true">
<cfset SpreadsheetObj = spreadsheetNew()>
<cfset fcol = {}>
<cfset fcol.dataformat = "@">

<cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(SpreadsheetObj, "Part Number, Description, Allocated, On Hand, Pending Receipt, Job Count, Qty Needed, Qty Issued, Order Count, Qty Ordered, Qty Shipped")>

<cfoutput query="getParts">
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="jobdata">
       select *
       from getJobs
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="orderdata">
       select *
       from getOrders
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>
     <cfquery dbtype="query" name="receiptdata">
       select *
       from getIncoming
       where partnum = '#getparts.partnum#'
     </cfquery>

     <!--- add all columns to an array --->
     <cfset aColumns = [ partdescription, receiptdata.recqty, jobdata.JobCount ] />

     <cfset SpreadsheetAddRow(SpreadsheetObj, ArrayToList(aColumns)) />
</cfoutput>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="#theFile#" name="SpreadsheetObj" sheetname="Sheet1" overwrite="true" />
```